# Maximum number of redirects exceeded from Nest,js, but from Postman - is ok

Tags: axios, request, postman, nestjs

Good day!

I get a problem.

I try do POST request from Postman, to my site, for auth, and everything alight, i got a response:

`{"state": "authorized"}`

But if, i do same POST request from my nest.js app to this site, i get an error like a - Maximum number of redirects exceeded.
I tried do this request trough axios, cross-fetch, HttpModule and etc. but every time i get this error...
I tried manually set "max redirect" param on 10, 20, 100, 1000+, and no thing changing... same error.
I try manually set "headers" from postman request, but no thing...

What i do wrong? Why same request from postman, works momentum, but from nest app, i got this problem?

Maybe i must manually set some settings for my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this helps me:
I just added in header of Axios request this:

`Cookie: "laravel_session=<TOKEN_FROM_POSTMAN>"`

I get this token from header of Postman request. I don't know what is this token... i hope it's permanent generated for my PC or etc. and he may works in future.